# Filename in chinese shows as unicode characters

Tags: emacs

when using C-x C-f, the filename which includes Chinese characters are shown as following:

[image]

How can I configure it to show Chinese words? Thank you.

=====updated=======

System: OS X 10.8.4

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin)

Comment: More details please - your operating system and version, version of Emacs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be caused by one of those annoying interactions between the operating system and Emacs. Emacs doesn't seem to know how to interpret the file names, so let's try to help it by inserting this in your .emacs file.

```
(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-file-name-coding-system 'gb2312)
(setq default-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))
```

You may need to try a different system instead of `gb2312`.

Comment: It looks like it is probably UTF-8 (\3xx\2xx\2xx being the expected sequence of UTF-8 bytes for a character in the han range).  But I would have expected that was the default for Mac OSX.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. `(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))` is ok, thank you so much.